# How do I display an alert in html using node, express and socket.io?

Tags: html, node.js, express, web, socket.io

I'm working on a web project. I'm using Express and Node.js to make it. The logic of the project is the following: it gets information from an html template, that is received by an index.js archive through a route, then the info is received by a method. The thing with the method is that it should display an alert box in the html file under certain conditions.

I made a little bit of research, and found that this is posible with the socket.io library. I tried to apply what I found, but it doesn't work. The process for this was the following: in the html file I created a method that uses some socket.io methods and it's supposed to receive a message from the server created with express. In the index.js file, I created an io object to creat a connection. Then, in the second .js file I had to call a socket.emit() method that is supossed to send the message I want.

Nothing of this works and I would like to know what's missing, or if there's another (easier) way to display the alert() in the html file of this project.

Here samples of the code I'm using. html.file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Text</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="/procesar-texto" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="texto">Write the info:</label>
        <input type="text" id="texto" name="texto">
        
    </form>
    <script  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@4.6.0/dist/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const socket = io();
        socket.on('notificacion',(mensaje) =>{
            alert(mensaje);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import express from 'express';
import multer from 'multer';
import http from 'http';
import {Server} from 'socket.io';
import {method} from './second.js';
//const app = express();

const app = express();
const servidor = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(servidor);
const upload = multer({ dest: 'imagenes/' });

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/file.html');
});

io.on('connection',(socket) => {
  console.log('Cliente conectado');

  socket.on('evento_personalizado',(mensaje) => {
    socket.emit('notificacion',mensaje);
  });
});

app.post('/procesar-texto', upload.single('imagen'), (req, res) => { 
  const info = req.body.texto;
  method(info);
  
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/file.html'); 
});



servidor.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Servidor iniciado en el puerto 3000');
});
```

second.js

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
export const method = async (info) => {
    const socket = io();

    if (condition) {
        socket.emit('evento_personalizado','Sí se pudo');
    }

};
```

Comment: This is a _very_ strange approach for this, but I think the main reason it's failing is because you do the request with an HTML form, which causes the browser go to a new page. I suspect you should probably just rewrite this to submit the data with `fetch()` by interecepting the form submit event and instead of using socket.io, have your server reply with a message.